# MongoDB 'not authorized on DATABASE to execute command' when not using MongoDBCompass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4

I'm trying to access data from a MongoDB which the database administrator has given me limited access to. The db admin has allowed me to access a specific document and collection within the db. For example, I can access the following:

| DATABASE | COLLECTION | DOCUMENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BOOKINGS | CUSTOMER | RESERVATIONS |

If I use MongoDB Compass, I'm able to successfully read the RESERVATIONS document within the CUSTOMER collection.

However, if I attempt to connect to the database through a web application, such as Pipedream, I always see the following error:

> `not authorized on <<DATABASE>> to execute command`

Would anyone suggest the issue? I have the correct credentials to provide the host, database, username and password (as well as authSource, replicaSet and readPreference) and it works in Compass, but doesn't seem to work anywhere else, or any other MongoDB query provider.

Comment: What third-party resource? Please provide all details. This resource may be executing operations that its not allowed to.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.